# TLS for ldap and certificate

Tags: httpd, openldap, tls

I have the httpd conf:

```
LoadModule  ldap_module  modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule  ssl_module   modules/mod_ssl.so

LDAPTrustedGlobalCert  CA_BASE64  /etc/openldap/certs/domenCA.crt

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      domen.lan
    ServerAlias     domen domen1
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/html

    <Directory  /var/www/html/private1>
        AuthName        "Members only site"
        AuthType        basic
        require         valid-user

        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPUrl      "ldap://ldap.domen.lan/dc=domen,dc=lan"
#        AuthLDAPUrl      "ldap://ldap.domen.lan/dc=domen,dc=lan"   TLS
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I run next and input the credential, it works fine :

```
elinks http://domen.lan/private1
```

then I try TLS (same but TLS on the end of line):

```
#       AuthLDAPUrl      "ldap://ldap.domen.lan/dc=domen,dc=lan"
        AuthLDAPUrl      "ldap://ldap.domen.lan/dc=domen,dc=lan"   TLS
```

It fails to show the page and I get error:

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

in `/var/log/httpd/access_log` :

```
"GET /private1 HTTP/1.1" 401 381 "-" "ELinks/0.12pre6 (textmode; Linux; 111x64-2)"
"GET /private1 HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "ELinks/0.12pre6 (textmode; Linux; 111x64-2)"
```

nothing in :

```
/var/log/messages
/var/log/httpd/error_log
```

when I run

```
openssl s_client -connect domen.lan:389 -showcerts -state
```

I get:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
140597450172320:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:184:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 249 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

I do not know how can I fix that cert eror.

I have

```
  centos 7.1

  openldap-2.4.39-6.el7.x86_64
  openldap-clients-2.4.39-6.el7.x86_64
  openldap-servers-2.4.39-6.el7.x86_64

  httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.x86_64
```

It seems to work ok if I have `TLS_REQCERT  allow` in `etc/openldap/ldap.conf` but not if I have `TLS_REQCERT  demand`. I can not figure it out what is happening:

```
TLS_CACERTDIR   /etc/openldap/certs
SASL_NOCANON    on
URI             ldap://centos7s.domen.lan
BASE            dc=domen,dc=lan
host            centos7s.domen.lan
#TLS_REQCERT    allow                    
TLS_REQCERT     demand
ssl             start_tls
TLS_CACERT      /etc/openldap/certs/domenCA.crt
```

Comment: What does your Apache/httpd error log say when the server returns code 500?

Comment: I updated the question. I added: `"GET /private1 HTTP/1.1" 401 381 "-" "ELinks/0.12pre6 (textmode; Linux; 111x64-2)"
"GET /private1 HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "ELinks/0.12pre6 (textmode; Linux; 111x64-2)"`

Comment: It seems to work ok if I have `TLS_REQCERT     allow` in `etc/openldap/ldap.conf` but not if I have `TLS_REQCERT    demand`. I can not figure it out what is happening.

Comment: The problem was that I was using a different server name when creating a certificate and now it did not want to accept the certificate. So, when I correct the line `        AuthLDAPUrl      "ldap://ldap.domen.lan/dc=domen,dc=lan"   TLS` with server name in certificate, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding your own sollution as an answer for readability:

> The problem was that I was using a different server name when creating a certificate and now it did not want to accept the certificate. So, when I correct the line: 
>   `AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://ldap.domen.lan/dc=domen,dc=lan" TLS` 
>   with server name in certificate, it worked!